# The method updateUI() of type ActivityMap must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: java, android

I am using a "template" for my Activities, i.e. a superclass called `AbstractMapActivity`
that is extended by my Activities.

For example `ActivityMap extends AbstractMapActivity`

I am creating an empty method in `AbstractMapActivity` that I want to override in `ActivityMap` but I am getting the following error:

`The method updateUI() of type ActivityMap must override or implement a supertype method`

**This is a snippet of the relevant code of `AbstractMapActivity`**

```
public class AbstractMapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


private void updateUI(){}
}
```

**This is the the snippet of the relevant code of `ActivityMap`**

```
public class ActivityMap extends AbstractMapActivity implements
OnNavigationListener, OnMarkerClickListener, OnMarkerDragListener {


@Override //HERE I GET "The method updateUI() of type ActivityMap must override or implement a supertype method"
private void updateUI() {
    //DO SOME STUFF

    }
}
```

Comment: @DerGolem Eclipse does not even let me do it :-(

Comment: nope, that's becuase you cannot override a private method (not visible)

Comment: @guido that's it! Thanks guido, if you post an answer i will gladly accept :-)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Override` annotation indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a supertype. If a method is annotated with this annotation type compilers are required to generate an error message unless at least one of the following conditions hold:

- The method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype.
- The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public method declared in Object.

In you case the `updateUI()` in the extended class is `private`, thus not visible outside it. Writing another private method inside the extending class, with the same signature, still does not make it overriding the parent class method, thus the compiler complains about the method annotated as @Override does not actually override any method.